# How to fill autocomplete one-time-code input by selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

html code:

```
<div class='UEclfJ _27cR_W'>
  <input type ='tel' autocomplete='one-time-code' maxlength = '6'>

  <input class='_1y306T _2ynKud' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
  <input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
  <input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
  <input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
  <input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
  <input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>

</div>
```

my solution:

```
        for i in range(6):
            cell = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@class='_1y306T'])[{}]".format(i + 1))))
            sleep(2)
            cell.click()
            print("click successful")
            cell_change = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input[@class='_1y306T _2ynKud'])")))
            print("cell exist")
            sleep(2)
            cell_change.send_keys("1")
```

It fails to send key one input one . Can somebody can help me to fill this input by selenium in python.Thanks you very much

Comment: Maybe you can try to use input_cell.click() before send_keys() and you don't need to move_to_element().

Comment: yeah i tried, it still fails, the input has 'readonly value' attribute so I think the problem is here